# Kotlin Permissions with Dexter go to settings Dialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apk

thanks for checking by. So I've been working on a project which ill expand/add some features to it eventually and currently im working on requesting permissions with Dexter (https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter). I've been able to get it working and when the user clicks on the Add Picture button it also asks the user for permissions, but I've encountered an issue I can't seem to solve myself. So the issue is if the user opens the app for the first time and clicks on the "Add Image" button and then chooses [User clicks on add picture button and chooses first option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aZ29.png)

And lets assume the user denies all permissions, if the user clicks on the button again the app asks for the permissions again but this time with the "deny and dont ask again" option. And I've built a small Dialog that pops up that explains why the permissions are needed and can lead the user to the settings. But I've found out that if the user actually allows the permissions on the second go the app still pops that window and I just wasn't able to solve it. 
[User allows permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6kgr.png)
[Msg still pops even though user gave permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqLYV.png)

Here is my code:

```
// Creating the variables of Calender Instance and DatePickerDialog listener to use it for date selection
// A variable to get an instance calendar using the default time zone and locale.
private var cal = Calendar.getInstance()

/* A variable for DatePickerDialog OnDateSetListener.
* The listener used to indicate the user has finished selecting a date. It will be initialized later. */
private lateinit var dateSetListener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_happy_place)

    // Adds the back button on the ActionBar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar_add_place)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    toolbar_add_place.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }

    // Initialize the DatePicker and sets the selected date
    // https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/android-datepicker-kotlin-example/
    dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        updateDateInView()
    }
    // Uses functionality in the onClick function below
    et_date.setOnClickListener(this)
    tv_add_image.setOnClickListener(this)
}

// This is a override method after extending the onclick listener interface (gets created automatically)
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v!!.id) {
        R.id.et_date -> {
            DatePickerDialog(
                this@AddHappyPlaceActivity, dateSetListener,
                cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            ).show()
        }
        R.id.tv_add_image -> {
            val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action")
            val pictureDialogItems =
                arrayOf("Select photo from gallery", "Capture photo from camera")
            pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems) { _, which ->
                when (which) {
                    0 -> choosePhotoFromGallery()
                    1 -> Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Camera selection coming soon",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
            pictureDialog.show()
        }
    }
}


// Method used for image selection from GALLERY/PHOTOS
private fun choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    // Asking for permissions using DEXTER Library
    Dexter.withContext(this).withPermissions(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ).withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
        override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
            // Here after all the permission are granted, launch the gallery to select and image.
            if (report!!.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@AddHappyPlaceActivity,
                    "Storage READ/WRITE permission are granted. Now you can select an image from GALLERY or lets says phone storage.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
            permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
            token: PermissionToken?
        ) {
            token?.continuePermissionRequest()
            showRationalDialogForPermissions()

        }
    }).onSameThread().check()
}

// Message to be shown if user denies access and possibly send him to the settings
private fun showRationalDialogForPermissions() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(
        "It looks like you have turned off " +
                "permissions required for this feature"
    ).setPositiveButton("GO TO SETTINGS")
    { _, _ ->
        try {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
            val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
            intent.data = uri
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }.show()
}

// A function to update the selected date in the UI with selected format.
private fun updateDateInView() {
    val myFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    et_date.setText(sdf.format(cal.time).toString())
}
```

}

As you can see im talking about the function "showRationalDialogForPermissions()" that gets initalized in the function "onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown".

If someone knows how to solve this or has any tips that I could give a go I would really appreciate it.

Kind regards,

EDIT: Also I've realised if the user clicks "Deny and don't ask again" and cancels my Dialog, the app doesnt seem to make the Dialog appear after that. Pretty much nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried a few things and I got it somehow working (there are still flaws)

I changed the following:

```
            R.id.tv_add_image -> {
            val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action")
            val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Select photo from gallery", "Capture photo from camera")
            pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems) {
                    _, which ->
                when(which) {
                    0 -> choosePhotoFromGallery()
                    1 -> Toast.makeText(this, "Camera selection coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            pictureDialog.show()
            addButtonClicked += 1
            if (addButtonClicked > 2) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@AddHappyPlaceActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        showRationalDialogForPermissions()
                    }
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@AddHappyPlaceActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        showRationalDialogForPermissions()
                    }
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@AddHappyPlaceActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        showRationalDialogForPermissions()
                    }
            }
        }
```

It's not an optimal solution but I just increment a value i created by 1 and once it reaches 3 (so assumed the user somehow managed to deny 2 times in a row) it pops that window up. Flaws would be that you somehow have to click the cancel button 2 times after giving permissions. But it somehow works and does what i was looking for; if someone has any different ideas, or ways to improve this "solution" it would be much appreciated